# Linux #open-file limit

Tags: linux

we are facing a situation where a process gets stuck due to running out of open files limit. The global setting file-max was set extremely high (set in sysctl.conf) & per-user value also was set to a high value in /etc/security/limits.conf. Even ulimit -n reflects the per-user value when ran as that head-less user (process-owner). So the question is, does this change require system reboot (my understanding is it doesn't) ? Has anyone faced the similar problem ? I am running ubuntu lucid & the application is a java process. #of ephemeral port range too is high enough, & when checked during the issue, the process had opened #1024 (Note the default value) files (As reported by lsof).

Comment: You shouldn't need a reboot. Try (as root) ulimit -Hn 100000, ulimit -Sn 100000 and restart your project under the same shell. You might also want to check /proc/sys/fs/file-max.

Answer (score 3):

One problem you might run into is that the `fd_set` used by `select` is limited to FD_SETSIZE, which is fixed at compile time (in this case of the JRE), and that is limited to 1024.

```
#define FD_SETSIZE      __FD_SETSIZE
/usr/include/bits/typesizes.h:#define   __FD_SETSIZE        1024
```

Luckily both the c library and the kernel can handle arbitrary sized `fd_set`, so, for a compiled C program, it is possible to raise that limit.

Comment: You should use something like epool for 1000+ files anyway. Maybe run with strace to see what system calls java is doing.

Answer (score 2):

Considering you have edited file-max value in `sysctl.conf` and `/etc/security/limits.conf` correctly; then:

```
edit /etc/pam.d/login, adding the line: 
session required /lib/security/pam_limits.so
```

and then do

```
#ulimit -n unlimited
```

Note that you may need to log out and back in again before the changes take effect.